# iPhone doesn't appear under 'Computer' in windows explorer

Tags: windows-vista, windows-explorer, iphone

I'm running a PC with Vista. My iPhone 4 when connected to the computer with a USB socket appears under 'Computer' in Windows Explorer.

I have another iPhone of the same model which doesn't appear as a portable device. How can I access this phone on my computer?

I have already tried:

- Disabling, and re-enabling the Apple Mobile Device USB Driver
- Unplugging and plugging back the phone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to unlock the phone and enter the passcode for the device to appear. I only noticed this when I opened iTunes and it asked me to enter a passcode.

Comment: Also, if your camera roll is empty, it won't appear in Windows Explorer